# Can I wrap some elements and not wrap others in the same flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex container with three elements. I want the first two elements to always stay in the first row, and the last element to fill the entirety of the second row. I need a dynamic change of the flex-wrap rule after the second element. Is it possible?

Please do not advise me to change the structure. I know it is doable with an inner container for the first two elements, but I cannot modify the structure; I can only add CSS rules.

Example is updated. Try shrinking the first column until the sort icon gets to the second row. I want the column title and icon stay in the first line and the search input in the second line. Something like https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

```js
var activeResizeHandler;
var clickEventX;
var originalWidth;
$(".resize-handle").mousedown(function(e) {
  activeResizeHandler = e.target;
  clickEventX = e.originalEvent.x;
  originalWidth = e.target.parentNode.clientWidth;
  $(e.target).addClass("active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  activeResizeHandler = null;
  $(".resize-handle.active").removeClass("active");
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (!activeResizeHandler) return;
  var newWidth = originalWidth + e.originalEvent.x - clickEventX;
  console.log(newWidth);
  activeResizeHandler.parentNode.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
});
```

```css
th {
  position: relative;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1ch;
  height: 100%;
}

th:hover .resize-handle,
.resize-handle.active {
  visibility: visible;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.first-child {
  margin-right: 1ch;
}

.second-child {}

.third-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <span class="first-child">Some unnecessarily long text to test</span>
          <i class="second-child bi bi-sort-down-alt"></i>
          <input type="text" class="third-child" />
        </div>
        <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want no wrapping, not sometimes wrapping, sometimes not. Or do you want the last element to take up both row 2 and an additional row 3, rather than just row 2?

Comment: Hey @TylerH, thanks for the edit and comment! I added a comment to Nikkkshit's answer. Hope it clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

- All you need is `flex-basis` propety.
- just set the all div to take whatever percent of space from available flex container.
- As you have used `flex-wrap:wrap`, it will breakdown overflowing element to next line.
- So, for your case, `chil3`, will be in new line, but as you want it to take 100% space, just add `flex-basis:100%` to `child3`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Adding this wraps the second element, too */
}

#container>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  /*50% because you want the first two to take all space*/
}

#child1,
#child2,
#child3 {
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  background: navy;
}

#child2 {
  background: green;
}


/*Specified container so we dont have to use important*/

#container #child3 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /*100% because you want this element to take all space*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

- Second Approach:
- You can add extra div, after the element you want break to occure.
- and same as above use `flex-basis:100%` on it.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
  width: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#child1,
#child2,
#child3 {
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  background: navy;
  width: 100px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

#child2 {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

#child3 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%!important;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like it makes element 2 the same size as element 1, which I'm not sure is what OP wants.

Comment: If that's the case I will add another approach for using extra div.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. I should have added that the container and child3 has variable widths. Like a resizable table header column. The first two has fixed sizes. I want the first two elements stay in the first line no matter what the container width becomes. And the third item go to the second line with full width.

Comment: Yes so my first approach is doing the same.

Comment: If you have seen it properly you can check that there is no height mentioned in any of child.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. I added a better example (with tons of bugs but it shows the purpose) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with `display: grid;`. Below is the working code.

```js
var activeResizeHandler;
var clickEventX;
var originalWidth;
$(".resize-handle").mousedown(function(e) {
  activeResizeHandler = e.target;
  clickEventX = e.originalEvent.x;
  originalWidth = e.target.parentNode.clientWidth;
  $(e.target).addClass("active");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  activeResizeHandler = null;
  $(".resize-handle.active").removeClass("active");
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (!activeResizeHandler) return;
  var newWidth = originalWidth + e.originalEvent.x - clickEventX;
  console.log(newWidth);
  activeResizeHandler.parentNode.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
});
```

```css
th {
  position: relative;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1ch;
  height: 100%;
}

th:hover .resize-handle,
.resize-handle.active {
  visibility: visible;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.group-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto min-content;
}

.first-child {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.second-child {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.third-child {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <div class="group-container">
          <span class="first-child">Some unnecessarily long text to test</span>
          <i class="second-child bi bi-sort-down-alt"></i>
          <input type="text" class="third-child" />
        </div>
        <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```